# BADROUTE error in rails when website under heavy load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, url-routing, internal-server-error

The website I am working on has occasional multiple FATALs in rails.log when in peak usage periods. Errors look like this:

```
[ERROR] (null):0 (null)(): (null): [BADROUTE] https://mywebsite.com/ directs to non-existant route: https://mywebsite.com/undefined
```

or

```
[ERROR] (null):0 (null)(): (null): [BADROUTE] https://mywebsite.com/some_path directs to non-existant route: https://mywebsite.com/some_other_path
```

Here, some_path and some_other_path can sometimes be completely unrelated. During normal operational load these errors do not occur. I thought that this might be due to users' mistyping urls, but after investigation it seems that urls are actually valid, and from user's perspective it just looks like website gave him "This site cannot be reached" error. Trying the same URL later might work.

What could be the reason for such strange re-routing? I have rails 3.2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is in your routes file?

Comment: The part that is responsible for this particular route looks like this: resources :docs, :only => [:show, :edit, :update] do
      resources :docs_transfers, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
    end

Comment: And there is a docs_transfer controller that has these methods. The controller and routing work fine most of the times, except when in peak usage hours.

Comment: Can you put the actual errors, rather than `/some_path` please.  Do you have redirects in your controller that causes the redirect?  Can you post that code too.